# Question on Faulty clock

Tags: arithmetic

> Clock A loses 4 minutes every hour, clock B always shows the correct
> time and clock C gains 3 minutes every hour. On a Monday, all the
> three clocks showed the same time, 8 PM.  On the following Wednesday,
> when the clock C shows 2 PM, what time will clock A show?

1. 7:20 am
2. 8:40 am
3. 9:20 am
4. 10:40 am

Kindly suggest how to approach this problem.

**My approach**
There is a lapse of 42 hours from 8 pm of Monday to 2 pm of Wednesday. As clock C gains 3 minutes every hour, the actual lapse should be 42 hours - (42×3) minutes. Further clock A gains loses 4 minutes every hour, so the lapse of time in clock A should be 42 hours - ((42×3)-(42×4)) minutes.
I couldn't proceed , also I am not sure if it's a right approach or if there's a better way to do this.
Kindly help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some information about what you might have tried so far, or (assuming this is homework) what kind of things you might have learned in the class that could be applied?

Comment: @ConMan I have added my thoughts.

Comment: You're a bit off, so I'll sketch out some details in an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have three "times" we can observe, one for each clock. If we knew the time on clock B, we could work out what time clocks A and C would show, but instead we're told the time on clock C and need to work out what time clock A shows.

As you note, if clock C reads 2pm then that means it is claiming that 42 hours have passed. So how many hours have actually passed?

- If 1 true hour passed, then C will show 1 hour 3 minutes as having passed.
- If 2 true hours passed, then C will show 2 hours 6 minutes as having passed.
- If $t$ true hours passed, then C will show $t$ hours and $3t$ minutes having passed. Or in other words, C will show $t \times 1 \frac{3}{60}$ hours passing.

Then if C showed 42 hours passing, then that means $t \times 1 \frac{3}{60} = 42$. Can you take this and rearrange it to find what $t$ is equal to?

Once you've done so, you can apply the same logic to finding the time on A - every hour that passed, A claims that only 56 minutes have passed. So if you know that $t$ hours have passed, A should show a time that is $56t$ minutes later.

Answer (score 1):

Let the actual time elapsed since $8 \text{ pm} $ Monday be $ t $.

The time reported by clock $A$ is $\dfrac{56}{60} t $ while the time reported by clock $C$ is $\dfrac{63}{60} t$.

Hence, from the time on clock $C$, we know that

$\dfrac{63}{60} t = 42 $

Hence,  $ t = \dfrac{(60)(42)}{63}  = 40 $

Thus the time reported by clock $A$ is

$ \dfrac{56}{60}(40) = \dfrac{112}{3} \text{Hours}$

Deducting $24$ gives a reported time difference of $\dfrac{40}{3} = 13 \dfrac{1}{3} \text{ Hours } $

Finally, $13 + 8 \text{p.m.} = 9 \text{ a.m. }$

Therefore, the time appearing on clock $A$ is $9:20 \text{ a.m.}$

Answer (score 1):

In $1$ hour, clocks A and C complete $\displaystyle\frac{56}{60}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{63}{60}$ revolutions, respectively.

Thus, they complete $1$ revolution in $\displaystyle\frac{60}{56}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{60}{63}$ hours, respectively.

When clock C displays $2$pm on the Wednesday, it has completed $42$ revolutions; this has taken $\displaystyle42\times\frac{60}{63}=40$ hours; concurrently, clock A has completed $\displaystyle40\div\frac{60}{56}=37\frac13$ revolutions; clock A then displays $8$pm$+\displaystyle37\frac13$ hours$=9{:}20$am.